# Visual Studio Code: How to "save as" all open editor windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, save-as

Sorry (to all/any) if this has been asked. But I can't find a match to the question (at least not one that I interpret as such anyway).

I'm new to Visual Studio Code and loving it. One the features I use a lot is having multiple editor windows open on the same file (i.e. to be editing different, but related sections of the code).

Now... If I use 'Save', all edits in all open windows are saved. However, if I 'Save As' the file is saved as a new file, but only the active editor window is now accessing that file. Any other open editor windows are still connected to original (i.e. pre 'Save as') version of the file.

This means (e.g. when simply amending the file version number) having to close all other windows, then reopen and get each back to the sections they where focused on.

Is there any way to tell VSC that a Save As should be reflected in all open windows (of the same file)?

Comment: then you could file a bug issue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Have done (and it's being treated a feature request).
See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129931
Mayhaps you could add your support (via an Upvote)?